# Multiple subscribers in ROS

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand it is okay to have multiple subscribers in the same ROS Node. However I am not sure how this works. My  ROS Node with multiple subscribers would be running on an ArduinoMega 2560 and would have 4 subscribers that are subscribing to velocity messages on 4 separate topics.

How would the subscribers and their callbacks respond to the msgs. Would they run in parallel or one after the other? And if they run one after the other would this depend on the order of the messages received or would it depend on where I call the subscribers themselves?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364849/multiple-subscribers-in-ros/) by [Abhinavgandhi09](https://answers.ros.org/users/40800/abhinavgandhi09/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-11-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-05**:
Please note: the OP is using `rosserial`, not `roscpp`. Answers will be different for `rosserial` and `roscpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know a perfect answer to this question, but this is how I'd like to put it. Cpp codes by default are single threaded and don't use multiple threads unless the multithreading library is used. Arduino itself is a single threaded microcontroller, so there's no question of subscribers running in parallely I guess. I think the subscriber callbacks would get executed in a serial fashion maybe in the form of a queue. `ros::spinOnce()` will make the code look for callbacks if any and execute them and the proceed with its function after callbacks are executed.

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2020-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1